# knockout viewmodel binding undefined error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sails.js

Even though i have defined my knockout view model , i keeps on getting an error ,

```
             **Uncaught ReferenceError: viewmodelname is not defined**
```

Some points that i noticed.

1. But my viewmodel file is loaded when i checked my page source.
2. Sometimes when i refresh the page , this error doesn't appear and the viewmodel is also loaded    properly.What could be the reason ?

   This is how i have given knockout binding.

   ```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
       if( !!$('#nf-list').length ){                                                                           
          var nf = new feed;
          ko.applyBindings(nf, $('#nf-list'));
          nf.init();
       } 
     });
   ```

   I am getting intermittently as : feed is not defined .

   Please help me to solve this.

Thanks !

Comment: Show the code. It will difficult to suggest anything without code.

Comment: This look's like an async issue ;) but as stated by Dnyanesh please show us some code, impossible to help you without.

Comment: async issue ?    Can u explain that ?

Comment: new feed should be like new feed() is what I think. And apart from that what is feed?

Comment: feed is my viewmodel name.

Comment: Still I am finding it difficult to suggest anything, I suggested one thing that is very obvious new feed should be like new feed(). But you need to share more code or share it in jsfiddle which will help us to understand.

Comment: Thanks Dnyanesh..Will try as u said first and then will share my code.

Comment: We need the code for the feed function. Do you have that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do it like this

```
function vm(){
    var self = this
    .
    .
    .

    self.LoadData = function(){
        // initialization code
    }

    self.LoadData()

}

ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

This never produces problem. LoadData will be called on initialization automatically.